# JavaScript Dropdown Form Validation: Throwing Error when a value of "0" is passed

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to create a form where if a value of "0" is passed, an error is thrown. I'm stumped and could really use some help. There are two functions in this script. The first is working, where I can change the URL based on the selection. Where I'm having a problem is I want the selection"--" AND "Choose State" to fire the second script that in theory would highlight the field and not allow the user to click. This is the function called "validateEmpty"

I'm totally open to a different approach, this is a hacked up version of a tutorial I found that passes a value.length of 0.

The sample page is here:
http://www.brimbar.com/no_crawl/js-test-homepage.html

OR

The code is below:

```
    <code>
    <div id="quoteDropdowns">
    <select id="stateType" name="stateType" onchange="dosomething()">
    <option value="select" selected="selected">Choose State</option>
    <option value="IL">Illinois</option>
    <option value="MD">Maryland</option>
    <option value="TX">Texas</option>
    <option value="VA">Virginia</option>
    <option value="--">--</option>
    <option value="other">Other</option>
    </select>
    </div>
    <div id="getAQuote"> <a id="mylink" class="myButton" href="#" onclick="validateEmpty">Get a Quote!</a> </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
function dosomething() {
    var inputSelector = document.getElementById("stateType");
    var link = document.getElementById("mylink");


    if (inputSelector.value == "VA") {
        link.href = "http://www.test1.com";
    } 
    else if (inputSelector.value == "MD") {
        link.href = "http://www.test2.com";
    } 
    else if (inputSelector.value == "IL") {
        link.href = "http://www.test3.com";
    }
    else if (inputSelector.value == "TX") {
        link.href = "http://www.test4.com";
    }
    else if (inputSelector.value == "other") {
        link.href = "http://www.test5.com";
    }
            else if (inputSelector.value == "--") {
        stateType.value.length == 0;
        link.href = "#";  
    }


    } 

    console.log('First Function is Valid'); 

    function validateEmpty(stateType) {

    var error = value.length==0;

     if (stateType.value.length == 0) {
        stateType.style.border = 'red'; 
        error = "The required field has not been filled in.\n"
    } else {
        stateType.style.background = 'White';
    }
    return error; 

}
console.log('Second Function is Valid'); 

</script></code>
```

Comment: please post your code in the question or in a jsfiddle

Comment: Yes, please don't ask people to reverse-engineer your page.

Comment: Hi Evan and Diodeus - I wasn't trying to get away with a fast one, I was having issues formatting my code for StackOverflow so I threw it on my testing server. I wasn't aware that was a faux pas. Thanks!

Comment: No worries try http://jsfiddle.net next time. It is quite easy to handle and it will be easier for others to help You.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) Ok, so You have decided to use the old, dark ways of inline javascript ;) instead of using Event Listeners, but why to setup href of the link element every time an option changes? It is not optimal. I would rather redirect when the link is clicked (on demand). This leaves You with only one function.

2) Instead of using `if..else` try to use `switch..case` construct it will ease things a little bit later. Moreover it seems more readable, but maybe it is more a matter of preference.

3) Why do You want to use such a twisted logic for validation? You already have a value of your select element which is '--'. Use it or You can also process it in default section of  `switch case` (see jsFiddle [example](http://jsfiddle.net/op1ekun/qm27a/11/)) this also handles "Select State" option. When You click on the link and the "wrong" option is selected You get a warning instead of redirect.

Here is my jsFiddle example: [example](http://jsfiddle.net/op1ekun/qm27a/11/).

Comment: Thanks! This is great. I'm new to programming so I'm learning by mistake and kindness of others.